# margin-left is adding space on right side of div

Tags: html, css

I am building a nav and when I put `margin-left: 20px` on my `nav ul li`, it is pushing the div from the right side outward. Text-align is right. Interestingly, if I switch the `float: left` to f`loat: right` on the `nav ul li`, it doesn't push the text out, but it does reverse the order.

Please be gentle, I'm new at this stuff :)

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
nav {
    margin: 20px 0;
    float: right;
}
nav ul li, nav ul li a {
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ff5800;
}
nav ul li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #44cc00;
}
```

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% I understand the question, but could the empty li (beneath your first 3 points) be giving the impression it is adding the margin on the 'wrong' side?

Comment: And that's why the internet exists :) That's what the problem was. Thanks!